# Find the height of the dam given angles of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, systems-of-equations

The top of a dam has an angle of elevation of 1.3 radians from a point on a river. Measuring the angle of elevation to the top of the dam from a point 155 feet farther downriver is 0.8 radians; assume the two angle measurements are taken at the same elevation above sea level. How high is the dam?

So I made two equations: y= height
1) tan (0.8)= y/(155+a)
2) tan (1.3)= y/a

So then finding the tan of those and creating y=..... and got:
1)y=0.0139635a+2.1643489
2) y= 0.0222693a

I set those two equal to eachother and I round to the nearest foot and keep getting 248 ft but it is wrong. I feel like Im doing this problem right, but somehow it's wrong Here's the pic:

[image]

Comment: In calculating the tan, you are confusing radians with degrees, as $\tan(0.8)=1.029639$ and $\tan(1.3)=3.602102$, whereas $\tan(0.8^\circ)=0.013964$ and $\tan(1.3^\circ)=0.022693$.

Comment: How did you get $y= 0.0222693a$ in the second equation? According to my calculator $\tan 1.3 \approx 3.602102$ so it's $y \approx 3.602102a$.

Comment: Oh becuase I was using radians on the calculator. Isnt that what I am supposed to do since it is given in radians

Comment: So I would use the degrees instead?

Comment: @Sondra - you should use radians, but I think you might have incorrectly used degrees instead, on your calculator. If you were to use radians, then you would obtain  $\tan(0.8)=1.029639$ and $\tan(1.3)=3.602102$.

Comment: If I do that I get 62 ft. But that is still incorrect.

Comment: @Sondra But 62 feet *is* the correct value for $a$. What formula did you derive for the height $h$?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to plug that value to get y the height. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent of the angle of elevation is the ratio of the dam height $h$ to the horizontal distance downriver of the observer. This gives us two equations for the height:

$$h=a\tan{(1.3)}=(155+a)\tan{(0.8)}$$

$$\implies a=\frac{h}{\tan{(1.3)}},~~~155+a=\frac{h}{\tan{(0.8)}}. $$

Subtracting the first equation from the second,

$$155=(155+a)-a=\frac{h}{\tan{(0.8)}}-\frac{h}{\tan{(1.3)}}=h\left(\frac{1}{\tan{(0.8)}}-\frac{1}{\tan{(1.3)}}\right).$$

Solving for $h$,

$$h=155 \text{ ft }\left(\frac{1}{\tan{(0.8)}}-\frac{1}{\tan{(1.3)}}\right)^{-1}\\
\approx 223\text{ ft }.$$